# Blocked but still shows "online" to blocked contact

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Please can someone help! I blocked a contact on Whatsapp but I can still see his "last seen" timestamp (as it changes over time - its changed many times since blocking). He can also see mine. I tried blocking with another person to test and it worked fine. 
Why can't I block properly for the contact I really want to block?

Comment: How do you know he can see your last seen time? If you block someone, you can still see his timestamp.

Comment: Are you sure about that? That I can see his but he cant see mine? I tried another thing. I added my own number as a contact, said hi :) then blocked it. Now, when I open that conversation, it says "online" or "typing" even though I am technically blocked.

Comment: Also - When I tested with the other person (that I dont actually want to block!) I could NOT see that she was online. So, A and B are both blocked. I can see A's timestamp changing, but I cant see B's timestamp changing.

Comment: That's odd. According to the [FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/21242423/), only your timestamp should be blocked to the other person, not the other way around.

Comment: I know! Thank you. So actually, I should be able to see B's timestamp changing?

Comment: If I understood correctly, yes.